# Completion of a ring and uniquely representation as a power series.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, power-series

It is known that if we take the ring of integer $\mathbb{Z}$ and fix a prime number $p$, the $(p)$-adic completion $\mathbb{Z}_p$ behaves like a formal power  series ring in the sense that every element in the $p$-adic integers can be written uniquely as 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_ip^i$$
where the elements $a_i$ are in $\mathbb{Z}$. I wonder if it is true in general, that given a commutative ring with unity $R$ and a principal ideal $I = (f)$, the elements of the $I$-adic completion of $R$ can be uniquely written as 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i f^i$$
where $a_i \in R$ for all $i \geq 0$.

Comment: I don't think what you said about $\Z_p$ is true unless you restrict $0\le a_i < p$ though.

Comment: @user37864 That is true. Nevertheless those $a_i$ are still in the "base ring"  $mathbb{Z}$.  If there is some restriction on the $a_i$'s in my question that is definitely something I would be interested in knowing.

Comment: You might find the Cohen structure theorem relevant. See https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0323.

Comment: The statement is not correct unless you restrict the $a_i$ to consist of exactly one representative of each coset of $I$. Any choice of representatives will do.